# Reading data file with conditional schema in python or pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, schema

I have a data file that I would like to process in python or pyspark but not sure how to define conditional schema. The layout of file is shown below:

```
10000012345,0,2,O,20081016,0.00,200.00 
10000011223,0,1,P,20190817,0,3.00,4.00
```

Check the fourth field, it can have value O or P, first three field will be common in every record.
Number and datatype for rest of the fields for record type O and P vary.

I need schema something like:

```
string field1, 
string field2, 
decimal field3, 
string field4

if field4 == "P"
  string field5,
  string field6
if field4 == "O"
   string field7,
   decimal field8
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.. your schema representation doesn't match with your conditional statements. Could you please describe in detail with some sample input file layout and your expectations on based on field4.

Comment: Vikrant, When field4 has value of "P" then field5, and field6 should be read and processed. When field4  has value of "0", then field7 and field8 should be used. Fields - field1, field2, field3 and field4 are common.

Comment: ..AFAIK a dataframe column in spark cannot have multiple datatypes for same column. You can either split P & O records in two files or load it into separate dataframe but yes you can select elements of your choice as shown below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your input file has 7 fields in the first record and 8 fields in the second record for respective 'O' and 'P' positioned at fourth place.

```
10000012345,0,2,O,20081016,0.00,200.00 
10000011223,0,1,P,20190817,0,3.00,4.00
```

I think what you are expecting can be done using rdd.

```
df = sc.textFile(path).map(lambda x: x.split(",")) \
        .map(lambda x :((x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[5],x[6]) if x[3]=='O' else (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[6],x[7]))) \
        .toDF(['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6'])

>>> df.show()
+-----------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|     field1|field2|field3|field4|field5| field6|
+-----------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|10000012345|     0|     2|     O|  0.00|200.00 |
|10000011223|     0|     1|     P|  3.00|   4.00|
+-----------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

I was not too sure that what other elements you wish to select for `'O'` and `'P'` fields at given position. As your expectation was not matching with the input file records.
So you can change your elements positions as per your requirement.

**Note-**
The rdd element having `'O'` and `'P'` will be positioned at `x[3]` as it starts from 0th position.